# Make the equivalent to a text request on youtube using python

Tags: python, youtube

I would like to make a text request using the youtube api.
For example i'm looking for all the videos that are related to 'frogs' and i would like to download the 10 first videos.

I already know how to download but i need a list of URL. i was thinking about something like this :

```
def get_url(string, url_number):
   liste_url = youtube.request(string)[:url_number]
   return liste_url
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch

videosSearch = VideosSearch('text', limit = 2)
```